# How can I invoke web-service if I have wsdl file without generating stubs java classes?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have only wsdl file and I know nothing about its content.
I have to implement two features

1. Get details information about all web-services (names and parameters) which are described in wsdl file
2. Invoke web-service without generating stubs java classes.

Comment: Why would you *not* want to generate the Java classes? And it seems like pulling out the info from a WSDL is self-evident, that's the point of WSDL files. What's the specific question?

Comment: I'm developing soapui like tool, and this tool gets wsdl files in run time and then invokes web-services and I don't have opportunity to generate stubs java classes because jre (not jdk) was installed on the customer computers

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to generate code to use JAX-WS clients - [example](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_dynamic) -  but you'll need to know something about the form of the requests/responses in order to invoke the service and interpret the response.

The WSDL describes the form of the SOAP payloads. SOAP payloads can contain all sorts of complex XML structures. The service might be able to describe all its constraints in the contract, but there may be logical constraints that aren't. There are a finite number of things you can infer from the WSDL.